# Android studio how to use getBitmap in Fragment instead of activity? Classifier 'ContentResolver' does not have a companion object

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I am trying to set a cropped image bitmap to an imageview in my View. In a Activity the code works but how can I apply this in a Fragment?

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    var result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data)
    var uri = result.uri

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(ContentResolver, uri)
        imageviewProfilePicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }
```

ContentResolver is giving an error:

> Classifier 'ContentResolver' does not have a companion object, and
> thus must be initialized here

I call the cropimage activity with this code:

```
context?.let {
        CropImage.activity()
            .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
            .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
            .start(it, this)
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `context.contentResolver` where you currently have `ContentResolver`.  You need to get a `Context`, because a `Fragment` (unlike an `Activity`) isn't a `Context` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

**Root cause**

To use method [getBitmap(ContentResolver, Uri)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media#getBitmap(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri)), you need to pass an instance of [ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver). In Android you can obtain an instance from Context class or its sub-classes such as Activity, Service, Application, etc.

Fragment is not a sub-class of Context, that why you can't obtain an instance inside Fragment directly. You can obtain via host activity (the activity that the fragment is attached to).

**Solution**

Change your code from

```
val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(ContentResolver, uri)
```

to

```
val contentResolver = requireActivity().contentResolver
val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, uri)
```